# Running shell command in a loop on every files to convert every file from scalar to corresponding csv

Tags: python, shell, csv, scalar

I need to achieve the following task, help will be appreciated.

I run a shell command as
`scavetool x A.sca -o A.csv`
This command with scavetool converts the scalar file into the corresponding csv file on my Ubuntu terminal. For example after running this command, it converts the `A.sca` file into corresponding `A.csv` file with the same name but only extension is changed to `.csv.`
Thus, I have `100` files starting  exactly like this `A-#0.sca`, `A-#1.sca` `A-#2.sca` and so on upto 100, and I want to convert them into their corresponding `csv` files like `A-#0.csv`, `A-#1.csv`, `A-#2.csv`, and so on upto `100`.

I need to do this in Python and I know how to run the terminal command inside the  python script which is through `os.system` as follow: 
for example `os.system("command")`

So far my code look likes this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv, os, glob
for file in glob.glob('*.sca'):
    os.system('scavetool x *sca -o *.csv')
```

However, the problem is, it converts all my scalar files into one single `.csv` file and I know it is because of `*` sign. But I have tried to loop through on every file as well but I do not get the desired output because with the loop my scavetool command complaints and I can not get the output for every single separate files as a separate `csv` file.

Please help to achieve this.

Comment: Before trying to execute commands, just print them... If you are able to print a list of all `*.sca` files along with the corresponding `xxx.csv` executing commands in a loop will be trivial. And anyway I cannot imagine another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search your files with `glob.glob("*.sca")`, so you know that all will end in `.sca`. The trick is just to forget the last 3 characters from all file name and add the correct extension. By the way, `format` is glad to repeat meny times the same replacement provided you give the number inside the curly braces (`{i}`). Code could become

```
for file in glob.glob('*.sca'):
    command = "scavetool x {0}sca -o {0}csv".format(file[:-3])
    print(command)   # to control the command
    # subprocess.call(command, shell=True)    # and execute when it looks correct
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but there is one more thing  which is like when i run the script it displays a a message on terminal about what the shell command does in the script, is there anyway I can disable it so that it should not be shown on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import subprocess, glob
for file in glob.glob('*.sca'):
    command = 'scavetool x {}.sca -o {}.csv'.format(file[:-4], file[:-4])
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Gl Hf :)

Comment: Hmm, your script is likely to try to convert A-#0.sca.sca to A-#0.sca.csv which is not really the requirement :-(

Comment: @Clem Thank you, but what should be inside these curly braces `{}`, because it throws error when I left it empty like you have mentioned. But even I also tried `command = 'scavetool x A-#{}.sca -o A-#{}.csv'.format(file, file)` but it throws this error `scavetool: Cannot open 'A-#A-#1.sca.sca' for read`. yes @Serge Ballesta is right.

Comment: @Serge Yes you're right, forgot the [:-3] to remove the files extensions. Linux-Fan : serge's modification do the trick :)